# Why does React's use of createRoot and ReactDOM.render have different synchronous and asynchronous behaviors for setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Regarding the following code:

```
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    console.log(this.state.count);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    console.log(this.state.count);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
      console.log(this.state.count);
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
      console.log(this.state.count);
    }, 0);
  }
  render() {
    return "123";
  }
}
```

If using ReactDOM.render the log will be 0,0,2,3， but for createRoot the log will be 0,0,1,1，Can someone help explain the reason?

Answer (score 0):

In React 17 and before, React used to batch state updates only from event handlers and React handlers. If we are using `setTimeout`, this is a different aysnc operation which is not tied to any handler. Here state batching was not done.

In React 18, automatic batching has been introduced for all contexts. Be it promises or async operations like `setTimeout` React will batch state updates.

With the above in mind, you can see why the above `setTimeout` in React 17 will cause 2 rerenders and in React 18 it will cause one rerender. If a rerender happens twice then `this.state.count`'s value will be updated once from 1 to 2, and then 2 to 3.

Now why the above code runs in React 17 mode, when you use `ReactDOM.render` can be seen [here](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#deprecations). Quoting from the docs:

> ReactDOM.render has been deprecated. Using it will warn and run your app in React 17 mode.